# How to make the strings, variables from TXT text to be Global in Main code

Tags: python

I'm trying to make Login/Register system. The only problem is now, How could I access the Variables and String globally in Main code? I know that defining them, is not very good idea. But i have tried to do that, and I do get error with variable, when i did this:

```
def Ballance(Ballance):
    global Ballance
    Ballance = 0.00
    return Ballance
```

And tried to use here:

```
print(" Ballance {} psw {} Your Ballance {} EUR ".format(Vardas, Password, Ballance))
```

I do get this in the terminal.

```
Ballance Jut psw jut Your Ballance <function Ballance at 0x7f6f0662bc80> EUR
```

My whole Code:

```
# Text File.
Database = 'Registruoti.txt'
check = True

def Vardas():
    global Vardas
    Vardas = input("~ Please pick a username for you Account!\n")
    return Vardas

def Password():
    global Password
    Password = getpass.getpass("~ Create a password for your account {}\n".format(Vardas))
    return Password

def Ballance(Ballance):
    global Ballance
    Ballance = 0.00
    return Ballance

def Role():
    global Role
    Role = 'Member'
    return Role

def Ban():
    global Ban
    Ban = False
    return Ban

def RegTime():
    global RegTime
    RegTime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", gmtime())
    return RegTime

while check:
    Register_Login = input("~ Welcome, LOGIN L, REGISTER R.\n")
    if "r" in Register_Login or "R" in Register_Login:
        with open(Database, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            Vardas()
            Password()
            #Vardas = input("~ Please pick a username for you Account!\n")
            #Password = getpass.getpass("~ Create a password for your account {}\n".format(Vardas))
            if " " in Vardas or " " in Password or len(Vardas) < 3 or len(Password) < 3 :
                print(" Cannot Contain null!")
                continue
            else:
                Gmail = input("~ Please add a Gmail for your account\n")
                if " " in Gmail or len(Gmail) < 7 :
                        print("Cannot Contain null!")
                        continue
                else:
                        # Setting up New account. Options Roles.
                        Ballance()
                        RegTime()
                        Ban()
                        Role()
                        f.write(f"Vardas : {Vardas} Password : {Password} Gmail: {Gmail} Ballance : {Ballance} BAN : {Ban} Role: {Role} RegTime : {RegTime}\n")
                        f.close()
                        break
    elif "l" in Register_Login or "L" in Register_Login:
        while check:
            with open(Database, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
                    Vardas = input("Please enter your Username!\n")
                    Password = getpass.getpass("Please enter your Password!\n")
                    for line in f:
                        if "Vardas : " + Vardas + " Password : " + Password + " " in line.strip():
                            print("You're logged in")
                            f.close()
                            check = False
                            break;
                        else:
                            clear()
                            print("Wrong password!")
                            check = True
                            continue;

print(" Ballance {} psw {} Your Ballance {} EUR ".format(Vardas, Password, Ballance))
```

My question would be how to use these functions as global, that I can use them without the defining?
**Password**, **Username**, **Ballance**, **Regtime**, **Role**, **Ban**.

Comment: You can't have a variable with the same name as a function. Rename one of them.

Comment: What do you mean same name as a function?

Comment: You have `def Ballance`, that defines a function named `Ballance`. Then you do `global Ballance`, that refers to a global variable with that name.

Comment: How could I for example edit them, from other functions. When I have the data in the txt file?

Comment: Stop using global variables in your functions. Just return the value, and have the caller assign to a variable there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to declare global variables with the same name as your functions. This is why you get the output `<function Ballance at 0x7f6f0662bc80>` - you are printing the function called `Ballance`.

You need to rename the global variables to something else, or better yet, use a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to collect the functions as methods, with attributes instead of global variables. You could try something like the following:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self._balance = 0.00
        ...  # more attributes

    def get_balance(self):
        return self._balance

    ...  # more methods
```

You would use this class like this:

```
my_bank_account = BankAccount()

...

print("Your balance is {} EUR.".format(my_bank_account.get_balance()))
```

You can add the code to initialise the attributes in the `__init__` method (either with a default value like `0.00`, or by prompting the user with `input()`). Then as well as `get_` methods, you can add methods to mutate the state, like this:

```
class BankAccount:
    ...
    def increase_balance(self, amount):
        self._balance += amount

    def decrease_balance(self, amount):
        self._balance -= amount
    ...
```

It sounds like you would benefit a lot from a good tutorial on Python classes, or about object-oriented programming in general. You should make sure you understand what `self` and the `__init__` method do above.

Comment: When i did this class, and used Bank as a variable I Do get this in Terminal: Ballance Jut psw jut Your Ballance <class '__main__.Bank'> EUR

Comment: @JamesSmith it sounds like you are printing the class instead of the result of the `get_balance` method. See update about using the class.

Comment: Yes, that's working. How to use this method with another variables and strings? Same method?

Comment: Also How could i add, minus to the balance? Which Do I need to use? my_balance or my_bank_account?

Comment: But, wait why there's  self._balance = 0.00 ? I just need to set the ballance to new account to zero.

Comment: @JamesSmith see update. To be honest, it sounds like you should read a tutorial on Python classes so you understand the basics.

Comment: Thanks, for advice and help. Maybe could you post a link of good tutorials about classes?

Comment: @JamesSmith I don't know a specific tutorial to recommend, just google "python classes tutorial". Alternatively you could have a look at some of the examples in the docs I linked in the answer.

Comment: After adding the decrease.balance and increase.balance I do get this error, after displaying the balance in the print function. 'float' object has no attribute 'get_balance'

Comment: @JamesSmith In general you should post a code snippet if you want help working out what is wrong, but try and understand what the error is telling you: you are trying to call `get_balance` on a float instead of your `my_bank_account` object. Can you see where you are doing that?

Comment: Kreditas = BankAccount(). To set up a new balance to new user I use Kreditas = 0.00. And to display it I use print(" Username - {} Password- {} Your Ballance - {} EUR ".format(Vardas, Password, Kreditas.get_balance()))

Comment: @JamesSmith right, so after `Kreditas = 0.00`, `Kreditas` is no longer an instance of `BankAccount`, it is just the number 0.00, so why would it have the method?

Comment: Hmm, that fixed it, now what about adding? When I tried this I do get an error. Kreditas.increase_balance += 20.00

Comment: @JamesSmith that is not how you call a method, you should really read a tutorial so that you understand the basics.